# How to get values from selected table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html-table

When the user selects a row using the checkbox option, and clicks 'Calculate Depreciation' I want to grab the values in {{asset.purchaseValue}}, {{asset.residualValue}}, {{asset.purchaseDate}} and {{asset.ddate}} to perform calculations to send back to the user. How can I get these values in jQuery, AngularJS or vanilla Javascript?

```
 <table align="center" class="assetlist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="45px">
                <select ng-model="sortBy" class="localSearch">
                    <option value="title">Title</option>
                    <option value="ddate">Disposal Date</option>
                    <option value="date">Purchase Date</option>
                    <option value="residualValue">Residual Value</option>
                    <option value="purchaseValue">Purchase Value</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Title" ng-model="searchString.title" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Purchase Date" ng-model="searchString.date" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Purchase Value" ng-model="searchString.purchaseValue" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Disposal Date" ng-model="searchString.ddate" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Residual Value" ng-model="searchString.residualValue" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="asset in assets | orderBy:sortBy | filter:searchString : searchStrict | limitTo: rowLimit">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/></td>
            <td>{{asset.title}}</td>
            <td>{{asset.date | date: "MMMM d, y"}}</td>
            <td>{{asset.purchaseValue | currency:"£"}}</td>
            <td>{{asset.ddate | date: "MMMM d, y"}}</td>
            <td>{{asset.residualValue | currency:"£"}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <button class="formbtn" ng-disabled="!checked">Calculate Depreciation</button>
```

Comment: Pass the whole object into a function using  `ng-click`

Comment: Check out my answer below. Let me know if that helps! :)

Comment: You can see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the row in when the user checks the box:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-checked="evaluate(asset)"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.evaluate = function(asset) {
  //var purchaseValue = asset.purchaseValue
  //var residualValue = asset.residualValue
  //var purchaseDate = asset.purchaseDate
  //var ddate = asset.ddate

  //do calculations
}
```

Comment: OP does not want it on checkbox click but rather on a button click which is outside the scope of `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Sajal From the OP's question: `When the user selects a row using the checkbox option` - that checkbox is a `td` on the row...

Comment: If the answer doesn't fix the issue, the OP should add a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co) so we can see the specifics about what's going on in the code...

Comment: Please view my CodePen for better understanding of what I wanted to achieve: https://codepen.io/cdochertyram/project/live/AnaKwM/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code for your desired output:(copy and try it!)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var purchaseValue,residualValue,life=1;
$(".ckb").on('click',function(){
var checked=$(this).is(':checked');

if(checked){
//checkbox checked
var tr=$(this).parent().parent().parent();
var titlevalue=tr.find('td:eq(1)').html();
 purchaseValue=tr.find('td:eq(3)').html();
 residualValue=tr.find('td:eq(5)').html();
}else{
//checkbox unchecked
}
});


 $("#calculateId").on('click',function(){

 if(residualValue==undefined&&residualValue==undefined){
 alert('please select the checkbox');
 }else{
// alert(purchaseValue);
 //alert(residualValue);
  var result=((parseInt(purchaseValue)-parseInt(residualValue)) /life);
alert('result:'+result);
 }

});


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" class="assetlist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="45px">
                <select ng-model="sortBy" class="localSearch">
                    <option value="title"> Title</option>
                    <option value="ddate"> Disposal Date</option>
                    <option value="date"> Purchase Date</option>
                    <option value="residualValue">residualValue</option>
                    <option value="purchaseValue">purchaseValue</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Title" ng-model="searchString.title" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Purchase Date" ng-model="searchString.date" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Purchase Value" ng-model="searchString.purchaseValue" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Disposal Date" ng-model="searchString.ddate" /></th>
            <th class="thead" ng-hide="hide"><input type="text" class="localSearch" placeholder="Residual Value" ng-model="searchString.residualValue" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="asset in assets | orderBy:sortBy | filter:searchString : searchStrict | limitTo: rowLimit">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="ckb" ng-model="checked"/></td>
            <td>title1</td>
            <td>date1</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>ddate1</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</form>

  <button class="formbtn" ng-disabled="!checked" id="calculateId">Calculate Depreciation</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, this is almost what I wanted to achieve- however this code outputs the the incorrect information.

I want to get the values in asset.purchaseDate, asset.ddate, asset.residualValue, asset.purchaseValue. I then want to output the following calculation to display asset depreciation to the user: ((purchaseValue-residualValue) /life). Thanks

Comment: instead of dynamic values I have taken the hard coded values.but the logic would be correct.Please see my commented variables //var date= & /var purchaseValue.. remove comments and do the calculation.

Comment: just for you, I modified the code.comment  if you face any completions.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are more than one asset, you should bind a new `selected` property to true(or toggle) for that asset on checkbox click as `ng-model="asset.selected"` in the `<td>`

```
<tr ng-repeat="asset in assets | orderBy:sortBy | filter:searchString : searchStrict | limitTo: rowLimit">
  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="asset.selected" /></td>
  <td>{{asset.title}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.date | date: "MMMM d, y"}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.purchaseValue | currency:"£"}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.ddate | date: "MMMM d, y"}}</td>
  <td>{{asset.residualValue | currency:"£"}}</td>
</tr>

<button class="formbtn" ng-click="calculateDep()">Calculate Depreciation</button>
```

In Controller,

```
//For Calculation
$scope.calculateDep = function() {
  angular.forEach($scope.assets, function(asset) {
    if (asset.selected) { 
      //Here are asset.purchaseValue,asset.residualValue ...
      //perform calculation individually for an asset
      //or send the enitire selected assets for calculation by creating a new scope array for selected ones
    }
  })
}
```

**UPDATE:**

See the snippet below, when you select one or more checkbox and calculate dep, you can see the entire object in the console.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.assets = [{
    title: 'Asset1',
    date: '',
    purchaseValue: 500,
    ddate: '',
    residualValue: 100
  }, {
    title: 'Asset2',
    date: '',
    purchaseValue: 500,
    ddate: '',
    residualValue: 100
  }];


  //For Calculation
  $scope.calculateDep = function() {
  console.clear();
    angular.forEach($scope.assets, function(asset) {
      if (asset.selected) {
         console.log(asset);
      }
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="asset in assets track by $index">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="asset.selected" /></td>
    <td>{{asset.title}}</td>
    <td>{{asset.date}}</td>
    <td>{{asset.purchaseValue}}</td>
    <td>{{asset.ddate}}</td>
    <td>{{asset.residualValue}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <button class="formbtn" ng-click="calculateDep()">Calculate Depreciation</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajal, please view my CodePen project for better understanding of what I wanted to achieve: https://codepen.io/cdochertyram/project/live/AnaKwM/

I have interpreted your updated code into my project but am receiving an NaN value. Why is this?